# Microservices - in an organization with multiple businesses

Tags: web-services, service, architecture, microservices, domain-driven-design

### Context

Let's say we have an organization that has multiple businesses. In this example, Business A sells a gigabit internet service to college students. Business B sells a megabit internet service to seniors. The businesses sell related products with slight variations, each targeting a different demographic.

At first glance, this seems like we can just have one application handle all the requests. However, it is natural for the businesses to diverge from each other given that they each target a specific demographic - by nature, each business will have its own business requirements. For example, Business A might expose a mobile application for customers to manage their account. Business B might expose a phone number that has to be called for customers to manage their account. The list goes on.

### What is the best way to utilize microservices given this context?

The problem is that there is both common and uncommon functionality across the different businesses.

We can remain somewhat DRY and have a set of base microservices (billing-api, order-api, etc.) that can be consumed by the different businesses. This works but this causes the microservices to have more "general" abstractions - leading to more complexity. For a concrete example, let's say the billing-api service has a /charge endpoint that is shared by Business A and B. Business B's requirement is to always discount $5 off the order:

```
//billing-api

if (businessB) { 
  orderCost -= 5; 
}
```

In this DRY approach, we would have an API gateway for each business (BFF pattern) which would aggregate different microservices to fulfill their business needs. All "business-specific" logic would get moved from the base microservices into the respective businesses' API gateway. In this discount example, instead of having an `if (businessB)` check in the billing-api endpoint, we can invert this control to the consumer:

```
//billing-api

const { orderDiscountAmount } = req.body; //body parameters

if (orderDiscountAmount > 0) { 
  orderCost -= orderDiscountAmount; 
}
```

Then the endpoint in Business B's API gateway would pass in an orderDiscountAmount of 5 when calling the billing-api endpoint:

```
//Business B API Gateway

billingApi({ orderDiscountAmount: 5 });
```

This seems fine, but all we did was take Business B's logic in the billing-api endpoint and created a generic (but forced) abstraction. This is "justified" by saying maybe Business A may use that one day - but that may never actually happen. Overall, this feels like an unnatural exercise for the developer and the consumer of the endpoint. Complexity and cognitive load on all sides are increased.

We can scrap DRY and avoid sharing microservices between businesses for maximum flexibility and simplicity. However, if more businesses are added (10-20) then there's probably going to be a good chunk of duplicated functionality.

### How should teams be structured given this context?

If we are okay with the DRY approach from above, how should teams be structured? We can have vertically-sliced feature teams, but does that mean if we have 10 businesses, a team would need to own a feature (i.e. checkout) on all the businesses? The drawback with this approach is that the feature teams won't be experts in any business as a whole - the teams would only be an expert in one feature in a given business. Not having the full context on a business could make it difficult to make the right decisions.

We can have a stream-aligned team for each business dedicated to the UI and the API gateway. We would then have platform teams creating microservices for the stream-aligned teams to consume. The drawback with this is that there is a handoff step between the stream-aligned team and the platform team, a.k.a a dependency.

I'm not sure if I'm looking at all this from the wrong lens - any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but this is not a good question for Stackoverflow, because any answer will be a opinion based and many approaches may work and depend on more details in your specific use case. So don't be disappointed if the question get's closed at some point.

That being said I am not too shy to offer my opinion or at least some thoughts about your described situation.

1. I believe your question about how to set up teams and how to set up the architecture are very tightly linked because architecture will with no doubt follow the organizational structure effectively. So I will give further thoughts about the organizational setup first.
2. An estimation of the total manpower required for each of the businesses should give you an idea of how many teams you need. Trying to keep team size small (say 2-8 people) will help reducing the communication overhead. So if you think this is the size for a whole business then there is no need to further split responsibility.
3. Responsibility is the most important keyword. You have to avoid any situation where a common service/library is used but has multiple or no owners. There should always be exactly one organizational owner. Thus, when organizations recognize the overlap of functionality in separate areas it is a common practice to establish a team that will be responsible and provide this functionality to others. This could be in the form of shared libraries or actually deployed services. In both cases it is important that the communication is formalized by correctly versioning their work and leaving it to the consuming groups which versions to use, when to upgrade, putting in requests for new features, etc. This approach will decouple the teams that use this common functionality.
4. In your problem description the core of the problem is the business logic and it's complexity / overlap. So I would argue that the most important role is the product management. They have to be very good (and at least a bit technical) and sort this exact mess into reusable pieces and things that are specific to only a single business. If you have a whole team of product managers they need to communicate very well and build this picture together. What is most important here is a good communication about the *vision* for the future and not just immediate requirements (Provide a great *domain view*). Only then can the architecture and teams be set up in the best possible way.
5. No matter how careful the initial setup - Changes WILL happen. Whatever you think in the beginning to be the best solution will change at some point in the future. In order to prepare for this I always recommend to go with the simplest approaches - Even if it means some code duplication or other imperfections. As software architects we tend to love the beauty of perfection, but that is rarely the most effective approach in the real world.
6. It is common sense to make a simple shared service/library that can be made to fit multiple use cases by adding some configurability. Up to certain degree of complexity that is a useful approach, but you have to be sensible to the consumers of that library/service and it should be easy to reuse at any point. It is not black and white about when to a functionality becomes too big / complex and has to be split into multiple pieces to be maintainable, but looking at it with the eyes of the maintainer and the eyes of consumer will make a determination easier. In the case of configurable service libraries you could also have separate deployments with different configurations, so using commonly developed components, but deploying different endpoints for each use case. If you use technologies that produce only a small deployment overhead (for example golang containers that are only a few mbs), then the large number of deployed services is not a drawback but a strength because they can be upgraded / versioned independently and it is even easy to run multiple versions in parallel.
7. Infrastructure and service deployment may or may not follow the architecture of the services. As a general rule I would recommend to look for the simplest approach, which often means providing common infrastructure that is shared among services and deployment configurations are where the distinction between services starts. For example a all services share a common cluster / streaming / gateways / databases / etc. Exceptions to that could be very special needs for single services, like a hardware encryption key store or GPU servers for machine learning, etc. This would be the approach for any reasonable sized system. (Of course if you are going scale to very large sizes it also a very feasible approach to have complete stacks / clusters for specific services.)
8. Persistency design is most crucial. Where it is relatively easy to evolve a business logic, reorganize it, etc., it is rather difficult to evolve your historic data. Often you have a choice to do a design in one of two ways:

   1. Smart algorithms, dumb data.
   2. Smart data, dumb algorithms.

(Smart referring to more elaborate / reflecting more of the business requirements)
The second approach is usually harder initially, but in my experience will have better results when a certain complexity threshold is reached.

So these are just a few things that came to my head when reading your question. I apologize that they cannot answer your detailed question about how to slice the billing API, but maybe you have a few additional considerations at hand.

Comment: All these considerations were really helpful. Great point saying the product teams need to build the vision together - I could see how that would influence the architecture and teams. I also like your guiding principle of leaning towards simplicity - seems pragmatic. I've never thought of viewing algorithms and data as smart/dumb. Thanks again, appreciate the lengthy response!